# C# Directives like #warning or #error but for information messages

Tags: c#

When you compile in c# you know that in list errors you have three tabs:

1. Errors
2. Warnings
3. Information

you know the directive #warning set messages in warning tab, #error set mesaages in error tab.

How can I do the same for Information tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

These directives output a specially formatted string that Visual Studio picks up, and it only responds to Error and Warning. Info can only be set by plugins (IIRC)

See

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx